# Keyboard Shortcuts Broken for Audio

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, audio

For some reason in the last few days, my keyboard shortcuts to adjust volume broke. I haven't done anything crazy - the only related thing I can think of is I added myself to the audio group so I could get audio over HDMI working (which, btw, was also weird).

Anyways, I didn't think it was a big deal - just go into Keyboard settings and fix the shortcut. Except whenever I try to set my shortcuts, it just acts like I hit `Escape` or something and they stay disabled.

I ran `xev` to double check what the system sees those keys as, and also recorded a video using Screencast which confirmed that the keys are being seen as `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`, `XF86AudioLowerVolume`, and `XF86AudioMute`.

For the record, I'm running eOS on a Toshiba Chromebook 2 (2015), with the i3 processor, so I have a chromebook keyboard layout. I ran fascinatingcaptain's script [from his github](https://github.com/fascinatingcaptain/CBFixesAndTweaks/) to remap the media keys and everything's been working fine.

Anybody know what's going on?

[Video trying to edit keyboard shortcuts](https://gfycat.com/SentimentalMatureAnemonecrab)

---

### Steps I've Taken So Far

Thanks @Sebastian for all the help so far. I followed your instructions for editing the key settings and then locking them down, and that seemed to make the settings stick. The media keys functioned normally. After a system restart it broke again. I can confirm that the keys are set properly, since `gsettings get org.gnome...` outputs what I would expect, i.e. `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`, etc. Also, trying to edit them spits back an error, which seems to confirm that locking them worked.

Here's the output from listing my current media key and keybindings:

`gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys | sort | more` yields:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Shift>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot '<Shift>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys calculator 'XF86Calculator'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys control-center 'XF86Tools'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings ['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys decrease-text-size ''
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys eject 'XF86Eject'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys email 'XF86Mail'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys help ''
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys home 'XF86Explorer'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys increase-text-size ''
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys logout '<Control><Alt>Delete'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys magnifier '<Alt><Super>8'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys magnifier-zoom-in '<Alt><Super>equal'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys magnifier-zoom-out '<Alt><Super>minus'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys max-screencast-length uint32 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys media 'XF86AudioMedia'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys next 'XF86AudioNext'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys on-screen-keyboard ''
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys pause 'XF86AudioPause'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys play 'XF86AudioPlay'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys previous 'XF86AudioPrev'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenreader '<Alt><Super>s'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver '<Super>l'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot-clip '<Ctrl>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot 'Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys search 'XF86Search'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys stop 'XF86AudioStop'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal '<Super>t'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys toggle-contrast ''
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys video-out '<Super>p'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down 'XF86AudioLowerVolume'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute 'XF86AudioMute'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up 'XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot '<Alt>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Alt>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys www 'XF86WWW'
```

`gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more` yields:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings activate-window-menu ['<Alt>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings always-on-top @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move ['<Alt>F7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-resize ['<Alt>F8']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close ['<Alt>F4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-group ['<Alt>F6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-group-backward ['<Shift><Alt>F6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels ['<Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows ['<Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward ['<Shift><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings lower @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-horizontally @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-vertically @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Super>h']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-center @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-ne @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-nw @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-se @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-sw @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-down ['<Super><Shift>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-left ['<Super><Shift>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-right ['<Super><Shift>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-up ['<Super><Shift>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-n @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-s @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-1 ['<Super><Shift>1', '<Super><Alt>1']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-2 ['<Super><Shift>2', '<Super><Alt>2']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-3 ['<Super><Shift>3', '<Super><Alt>3']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-4 ['<Super><Shift>4', '<Super><Alt>4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-5 ['<Super><Shift>5', '<Super><Alt>5']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-6 ['<Super><Shift>6', '<Super><Alt>6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-7 ['<Super><Shift>7', '<Super><Alt>7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-8 ['<Super><Shift>8', '<Super><Alt>8']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-9 ['<Super><Shift>9', '<Super><Alt>9']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-last ['<Super><Shift>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Super><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Super><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Super><Shift>Page_Up', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu ['<Super>space', '<Alt>F2']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-run-dialog @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise-or-lower @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings set-spew-mark @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['<Super>Down', '<Super>s']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group-backward ['<Shift><Super>Above_Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group ['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels ['<Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 ['<Super>1']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 ['<Super>2']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 ['<Super>3']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 ['<Super>4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 ['<Super>5']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 ['<Super>6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 ['<Super>7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 ['<Super>8']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 ['<Super>9']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-last ['<Super>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['<Super>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right ['<Super>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows ['<Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward ['<Alt><Shift>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-above @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-fullscreen @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized ['<Super>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-on-all-workspaces @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize ['<Alt>F5']
```

---

### Final Solution (Sort Of)

<del>I followed the suggestions from @Sebastian to edit the key settings and then lock them, but did so in a root shell, which seems to let the settings persist through reboots.</del>

Follow up - shortcuts don't persist through reboots anymore. But the shortcuts can be made to stick, at least temporarily, but editing the settings in a root shell, locking them, and then updating dconf via `dconf update`. I'll probably just make a script to do this on startup for now until it gets fixed upstream.

Comment: to improve the info: which version of elementary you use?

Comment: I'm running Juno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible solution

Install `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Run `dconf-editor`

go to:

```
org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > media-keys
```

Look after `volume-*` related entries

[image: dconf-editor-volume-entries]

Enter the proper values there and check again, maybe a relog or reboot could be useful to start clean after the change

---

If you want to use commands instead of `gconf-editor`:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down XF86AudioLowerVolume`

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up XF86AudioRaiseVolume`

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute XF86AudioMute`

---

To confirm/**check** each key

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down`

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up`

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute`

---

### List Current Media & Gnome Keymap

`gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys | sort | more`

`gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more`

---

### Lock down specific settings

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-background.html.en

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!

No idea why they got messed up, but good to know about dconf-editor.

Editing the keyboard shortcuts via Settings is still broken though, but for now I'll use dconf-editor.

Comment: I recommend you to go and report the issue on github, that way it could get fixed. https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard

Comment: I don't know what has happened upstream, but the audio keys broke again, and no amount of finaggling in `dconf-editor` will fix it. Super frustrating. I found a similar issue filed on github so I added on with my two cents: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/194

Comment: list (editing your question) your keymap, maybe there's the answer. I just added some commands for it

Comment: also check the lock settings (two links at the bottom), maybe if you set them as system-wide as root and them lock them nothing will change them

Comment: I'll try locking them again as root and see if that makes it stick.

Comment: Dropping into a root shell and resetting the keys and locking them again did it, and it survived a reboot! Man that was crazy. I really appreciate the help @Sebastian.

Comment: Glad to help...